# Rails and database column prefixes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema

I am working on a large web app and our database schema is such that most table columns (id columns being one large exception) are prefixed with an abbreviation of the table name.

We'd like to port the app to Rails but it appears that, according to Rails practices, column names should not be prefixed in this way.

Is it possible to use rails with column name prefixes?  I know table name prefixes are supported, but I didn't see anything about column names.

Any Rails experts out there have any thoughts?

Comment: did you try to run a rails g model aTableName.  where aTableName is a table in your BD.  This way you could see how rails behave with the fields.

Comment: I'll look into that.  I would assume that, for columns that aren't special like `id` or `office_id` etc., Rails would just interpret the column as being the name of a property in the model instance.  I would assume that would work fine.  Not established practice, though, which is bothersome.

Comment: indeed, your id will be the primary id and the office_id would be a foreign key.  for the other fields, i just assume rails will let you access them with the name of the column!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can't see any problem with prefixed columns (put aside it's a bit boring to use).

Anyway, say you have a User model with `u_name` for `name` etc...

It would be cool to do: `User.first.name`

instead of:  `User.first.u_name`

To achieve that, I suggest this untested meta programming that you should put in an initializer.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.pretty_columns(prefix)
    skipped_columns = ["id"]       #add whatever column name you want here  
    columns.each do |column|
      column_name = column.name
      unless skipped_columns.include? column_name
        unprefixed_col = (column_name.scan /^#{prefix}(.*)/).flatten.first 

        define_method "#{unprefixed_col}" do
          self.send "#{column_name}"
        end

        define_method "#{unprefixed_col}=" do |value|
          self.send(column_name, value)
        end         
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  pretty_columns :u_
end
```

Comment: Okay, cool.  Looks like that would dynamically generate methods which would wrap to the correct ones.  I'll consider this, but I might just do some careful refactoring and migrate the schema to something that would be more natural for Rails.  We'll see...

Comment: There's also a variety of other generated methods that you'd need to define here such as field_was?, field_changed?, etc. So this solution strikes me as a bit a hack.